# 'for' loop inside the code snippet not understood

Tags: scala, for-loop

I have below piece of code, which is printing: Some(600) as output.

Its not understood how the addition is happening inside 'for' loop.

In below, its confusing whats happening inside the code block of 'for' loop and how the variable 'y' is being calculated. Can someone please help?

```
 object TestObject extends App
{
  def toInt(s: String): Option[Int] = {
    try
    {
      Some(Integer.parseInt(s.trim))
    }
    catch
      {
        case e: Exception => None
      }
  }
  val y = for
    {
    a <- toInt("100")
    b <- toInt("200")
    c <- toInt("300")
  } yield a + b + c
  println(y)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Scala this is called a [**for-comprehension**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html).

`toInt` wraps the value in an `Option` which is extracted by `<-` and assigned to `a` and so on.

If one of the `Option` is `None` the result would be `None`

`yield` always returns its last statement, in your case: `a + b + c`

And so the result is `Some(600)`.

See the documentation here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html

Answer (score 0):

From inside the **for** loop, **toInt** method is being called which returns an **Option[Int]**. Now what for loop does is to simply **`open the Option container and assign variable`** a with value of 100. On similar lines, variables b and c are assigned value of 200 and 300.

And in the end the **yield** statement adds the values a,b and c and puts it back in the **Option container**.

Please refer to https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html and https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-for-loop-yield-examples-yield-tutorial